# Android Version Code different then what Play Console shows me

Tags: android, google-play

When I do the following in `/android/app/build.gradle`, in my Google Play console it says my "Version code" is **18**. Does anyone know why this would happen?

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.8.0"
    }
```

Comment: You sure you don't have something else overriding this version code? The issue might not be with Google Play Console, but with your project or Android Studio. Here's something to check: after you build your apk, inspect that file with `Build > Analyze APK`, go to the manifest, and take a look at the version code that's there.

Comment: @TWL Weird it is showing 18 as well. What I don't understand is I exported the app when it was VersionCode 1 and it showed that on Google Play. The only thing I changed was the Version Code and now it's showing 18. It's not like it was ALWAYS 18